# Automatically change a column within a specific amount of time in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a `reset` table on MySQL.

```
id | email | token | created_at | status
```

created_at is of type timestamp while status is varchar (active/inactive). By default, every insertion registers the status as active. What I want to happen is that after 10 minutes from the registered created_at, the status should automatically update to inactive.

I tried doing this

```
Update reset
SET `status`= 'inactive'
WHERE `created_at`> NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE;
```

but status still hasn't changed from active to inactive after 10 minutes.

Comment: `<` instead of `>`

Comment: You could also use [Computed/Generated columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117600/computed-generated-columns-in-mysql-5)  (Mysql 5.7+)

Answer (score 1):

A better design/approach here would be to just compute the active/inactive status when you go to query:

```sql
SELECT
    created_at,
    CASE WHEN created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
         THEN 'active' ELSE 'inactive' END AS status
FROM reset
ORDER BY created_at;
```

Don't set out to continually update your data, but rather let your logic interpret the data as you need.

**Edit:**

If your actual requirement is to view only inactive records, then use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM reset
WHERE created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE;
```

Comment: Tried this solution. Correct me if I'm wrong but this query, assuming 10 minutes have passed, would show that the status is inactive but in the actual database, the status is still active, right?

Comment: Yes...but why does that even matter to you?  Your ultimate requirement is to be able to pick a record and be able to articulate whether that record be active or inactive.

Comment: It doesn't really matter to me. It's just that when I tried your query, it still shows all the records. Is there a way wherein I can only show the record with the status that is already inactive? Because although the query works, it will still show results even if their status is still active

Comment: @rinrin if an answer has been helpful in some way, it's common practice on this site to acknowledge that. And if it happens to resolve your issue then an 'accept answer' button is provided. This lets other potential contributors know that the problem is now resolved.